# Slices - retain header and footer and edit middle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, html

I have an email template that's done in Photoshop for a weekly newsletter. It's sliced up and the only parts that stay the same are the header and the footers, the height of the email is always different.

What would be the best way to just change the middle part when creating a new email, leaving the top and the bottom as an asset? Should they just sit in separate PSD files and then be combined after it's saved to HTML?

Comment: What does EDM stand for? Probably not my first guess, which is electronic dance music... ;)

Comment: Electromagnetic Distortion Modulator?

Comment: @JohnB just doing mail outs ;) I think it probably stands for Electronic Direct Mail

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed email, you can't really use background images in CSS, or rather you shouldn't. It's best to create the traditional table layout and place the header and footer in table cells. Then it's a really easy matter to edit the middle content.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use the Save for Web feature as much as possible.

Comment: You can set a header and footer image in separate pSD files. Then edit and resave. As long as the file name and dimensions don't change they should swap out seamlessly

Comment: Backgrounds can be used in html email utilizing a [combination of CSS `background` and Microsoft's VML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953246/hotmail-not-showing-html-or-css-background/15955279#15955279).

Comment: Of course, not every mail client will support Microsoft VML.

Comment: VML is the hack for Outlook, the rest of the major clients support `background` in both table and body tags. See [backgrounds.cm](http://www.backgrounds.cm) for more info on how a "bulletproof" background using both techniques works.

Answer (score 1):

> Should they just sit in separate PSD files and then be combined after
>   it's saved to HTML?

YES. You should never use Photoshop slices for html email. Separate your header and footer images and create the rest in code.

If you have any further questions on the code side, stackoverflow's [html-email section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-email) is the place to go. Here are a few links you might find also find helpful:

- [HTML Email Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734)
- [Campaign Monitor Free Templates](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/)